# ios write something on my friend post on facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

i am new in ios , i want to write something on my friend post . i am try this code using graph
api this is not working please help me

```
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [params setObject:@"Some text" forKey:@"user_message_prompt"];
    [params setObject:@"another text" forKey:@"action_links"];
    [params setObject:@"Yet another text" forKey:@"attachment"];
    [params setObject:@"SOME FACEBOOK ID" forKey:@"target_id"];




    FBRequest *request = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession
                                                  graphPath:@"https://graph.facebook.com/100000329153640/feed"
                                                 parameters:params
                                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSLog(@"%@",request);
```

in this **NSlog-- request** line return this

```
graphPath: https://graph.facebook.com/100000329153640/feed, HTTPMethod: POST, parameters: {
    "action_links" = "another text";
    attachment = "Yet another text";
    "migration_bundle" = "fbsdk:20131212";
    "target_id" = "SOME FACEBOOK ID";
    "user_message_prompt" = "Some text";
}>
```

please give me solution 
please share your valuable knowledge ... i am waiting 
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [params setObject:@"Some text" forKey:@"user_message_prompt"];
    [params setObject:@"another text" forKey:@"action_links"];
    [params setObject:@"Yet another text" forKey:@"attachment"];
    [params setObject:@"SOME FACEBOOK ID" forKey:@"target_id"];

    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                       parameters:params
                                          handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                              NSLog(@" RESULT : %u",result);
                                          }
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer Developer Guide for facebook

[Facebook Developer guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is request publish permissions. I wrote this helper method to do it:

```
void runBlockWithPublishPermissions(void (^block)(FBSession *))
{
    FBSession *session = [FBSession activeSession];
    NSString *publishPermission = @"publish_actions";
    // If we already have publish permissions, then submit.
    if (([session isOpen] && FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(session.state)) &&
        [session.permissions containsObject:publishPermission])
    {
        block(session);
    }
    // Else request for the permissions, then submit.
    else
    {
        [session requestNewPublishPermissions:@[publishPermission]
                              defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                if (!error)
                                {
                                    block(session);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    NSLog(@"Failed to request publish permissions: %@", error);
                                }
                            }];
    }
}
```

You would then use your code in the following way:

```
void (^submit)(FBSession *) = ^(FBSession *session){
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [params setObject:@"Some text" forKey:@"user_message_prompt"];
    [params setObject:@"another text" forKey:@"action_links"];
    [params setObject:@"Yet another text" forKey:@"attachment"];
    [params setObject:@"SOME FACEBOOK ID" forKey:@"target_id"];

    FBRequest *request = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:session
                                                  graphPath:@"https://graph.facebook.com/100000329153640/feed"
                                                 parameters:params
                                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:nil];
};
runBlockWithPublishPermissions(submit);
```